# What is this red circle icon upper right corner next to keyboard settings?

Tags: icons

[image]

When I click it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an indicator without a proper icon.  Dropbox is probably the most common app that does this, but there are others.

Comment: If it's dropbox, I suggest this project: https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox

Answer (score 0):

I think it means something has downloaded, not sure though. I don't have it, maybe try a reverse image search on google